# variable amount of variables in calculation python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm extremely new to python and can't google my way out of this issue i have.
Basically I don't have a good idea how to approach the following issue:

From a database i pull a blend composition a blend consists of layers and layers consist of raw materials. 
Now i need to go over some calculations with the layers and see how certain raw materials within one displace others. I figured out the calculation I want to use but I have set it up to handle just 2 layers at the moment. 
The layers range between 2 and 8, I was wondering if it is possible to make a function which can handle the variable amount of variables in the calculation?

Now i have googled args and kwargs but can't find my way around them.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how I would even begin to tackle an issue like this?
example calculation:

```
x,y,z = symbols(['x','y','z']) 
r =  symbols('r')


layer2 = lyrcfg2 *(x * 0.06 + y * 0.64 + z *0.30)
layer2_initial = (x * 0.06 + y * 0.64 + z *0.30)
#r makes up for 100% of this layer
layer1 = lyrcfg1 * r
i=0
j=20
layer2_constant = lyrcfg2 - (lyrcfg2*trim_2 + trim_1*lyrcfg1)
l2_start = layer2_constant * layer2_initial

while i<j:
    layer2 = l2_start + trim_1 * layer1 + trim_2 * layer2
    i += 1
    print i,layer2
```

Comment: You might want to create a simplified example of what you are trying to do, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: mm, So suppose you have layer a and b. layer a= 3z + 5x b= 4p +2k. now i take a part of layer b and put that back into layer a. so a part of that layer is going into a and i need les of a. now imagina doing that for 8 layers. the calculation above is bigger because layer a also refeeds in itself so that is why there are loops eventually it balances out due to a a max amount of refeed. editing the main text

Comment: Are you performing different types of calculations based on the number(type) of layers? Or are you performing the same calculation for each layer?

Comment: there is only 1 calculation and that is to find out the composition of the layer where all the "junk" is being fed into. I just need to be able to make sure every layer's junk is accounted for

Comment: for the individual layers i just need to find out how much junk there is which is simply a percentage multiplied by their composition. then i need to refeed those into the replacement layer.